# Edit multiple cmd files in a directory

Tags: file, replace, directory

I tried to adapt some script that I found here but with no success..

I have to edit almost 300 logonscript's (example.cmd)
I would like to have a script that look's in to a directory (C:\temp) and replaces AAAA to BBBB in all files.
any help?

Comment: You should post your script, and tell us what about it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need this to solve only a specific problem.

You can do it using **Notepad++**:

- Search > Find in Files ... (Ctrl + Shift + F)

There you can find "Find what" and "Replace with".